# Jquery ajax call - how to alert the value from the return object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

My requirement is to get the proper value. I got the success alert.  result set contains one and only one value. How can I show/alert that value in result?

```
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: getDatawithToken(params),
        success: function (result) 
        {
             alert("success");  
             if(result.d.length>0)  
                {
                    alert("success");   
                }            

        }
    });
```

Comment: try `alert(result.d[0])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: getDatawithToken(params),
    dataType : 'json', // expecting json returned from server
    success: function (result) 
    {
         alert("success");  
         if(result.d.length>0)  
            {
                // access first element 
                alert(result.d[0]);   
            }            

    }
});
```

Comment: This is my result set :   [{"BlockRefHandle":"11B67"}]    I need to get  only 11B67 . How can we do?

Comment: try `result[0].BlockRefHandle`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to see the data in json, in jquery write console.log(result) and check what you want to retrieve in browser console. This is the best way to debug json.

Answer (score 0):

By typeing `alert(result)` in you success function, `result` is the object returned by the ajax call

Comment: return data is in  json.

Comment: replace it with a `console.log(result)`, go the the console and you should see the json object there, paste it here so i can help you

Answer (score 0):

try this , you can explore result value in console.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: getDatawithToken(params),
        success: function (result) 
        {
             alert("success");  
             if(result.d.length>0)  
                {
                    Console.log(result)   
                }            

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See console output (CTRL/CMD+SHITF+I) to degub, seeing what coming form server:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: getDatawithToken(params),
        success: function (result) 
        {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have json string so please parse that to object.

Using JSON.parse(result.d);

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: getDatawithToken(params),
        success: function (result) 
        {
             alert("success");  
             var jsonObject=JSON.parse(result.d);
             if(jsonObject.length>0)  
                {
                    Console.log(jsonObject[0].BlockRefHandle);
                }            

        }
    });
```